# SPContext.Current is null in Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)

Tags: development, workflow, workflow-activity

I have a custom workflow action derived from `SequenceActivity`

```
  protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
        {
            var current = SPContext.Current;
            //current is null
         }
```

The code I copied is largely from another custom action, which is working as expected.  I definitely missed something when copying things over and creating the new action, but I am not sure where to look.

Comment: There are normally 2 places to check: your Custom Activity and your .actions file. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1257293/98933

Comment: Kit, I checked out your suggestion.  I added a Dependency prop for context and a parameter in the .actions file.  The "Context" dependency property is null when I step into the action's Execute method.  Could there be something I am missing higher up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem your getting is correct and should be null ;) why? because workflow run under different thread to the current context ;) so instead of SPContext.Current you need to use WorkflowContext!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowactions.workflowcontext_properties.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowactions.workflowcontext.aspx

```
public static DependencyProperty __ContextProperty = System.Workflow.ComponentModel.DependencyProperty.Register("__Context", typeof(WorkflowContext), typeof(YourActivityClass));

 [Description("Context")]
 [Category("Context")]
 [Browsable(true)]
 [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
 public WorkflowContext __Context
 {
     get
     {
         return ((WorkflowContext)(base.GetValue(YourActivityClass.__ContextProperty)));
     }
     set
     {
         base.SetValue(YourActivityClass.__ContextProperty, value);
     }
 }
```

more details on the above code is here:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davidbi/archive/2008/07/21/How-to-get-the-context-item-in-workflow-activity-sharepoint.aspx